# Can I implement rich text via invisible textarea over a pre?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to implement a syntax highlighting feature in my app.
Please ignore the possibility of contenteditable.

I'd like to implement the feature via:
textarea with invisible font and background, floating over a pre with appropriate colors applied to the text. The cursor and selection background should render in the textarea, but the highlighted text should show through from the underlying pre.

Now, it seems there is something special about textarea (or my CSS ignorance) that makes this not render correctly (e.g. making background/color of a textarea also makes the cursor invisible).

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

I don't need general help. Attached is an image of my editor in action. Highlighting and selection are visible, cursor is not. :(.

[image]

Comment: you can get inspiration from https://github.com/search?q=syntax+highlighting

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to solve the very specific detail I've asked for. I have a parser. I'm generating syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use thee CSS-property [caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) for the textarea. This will set the color specifically for the cursor/ caret and ignore the color of the background/ text for the textarea. This does unfortunately not work in IE/ Edge (It is however supported by the remaining major browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I clearly did not get what you meant before and pointed you toward a code editor like [ace](https://ace.c9.io/).

I see now I just created the example of what you asked above. You can hide the text in the textarea by doing something like this color: rgba(0,0,0,0); But that will also hide the cursor.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{
  position: relative;
}
pre{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>This is my pre
      -
      -
  </pre>

  <textarea>This is my pre</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm doing custom editing, custom parser, custom highlighting. Ace is not what I need. And why would you say "You can not accomplish Syntax highlighting by floating a textarea over a pre element"? I actually almost have it working.

Comment: Your OP is tagged CSS and HTML not even JS. So I did not think it was possible by just using these techniques.

Comment: The problem I'm having has nothing to do with javascript. It's purely a display issue.